# Cointegration - Interpretation of result

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, cointegration, eviews

When performing Johansen cointegration test between two I(1) variables, I got the following result (sample size 2011)

[image]

What confuses me is that in models 3 and 5 there are 2 cointegrating relations. However, as I have two variables there should be max 1 cointegrating relation.

How should I interpret the above result?

Comment: If there are as many cointegrating relations as there are variables, the implication is that all variables are $I(0)$.

Comment: @hejseb, thank you for the responce. However, the variables are not I(0) but I(1). Is it possible that (a) model 3 is not appropriate (b) since p-value for cases 3,5 are around 0.04 there exists a type I error ? Plus, when I lower the sig level there exists only 1 relationship.

Comment: For one, it’s not uncommon for tests to disagree. Unit root tests are notoriously unreliable for small sample sizes. Second, you should really think about the specification of your cointegrating relation and stick to that. The table you have provided includes several uninteresting tests (because presumably there’s one configuration you believe is more appropriate).

Comment: my sample is 2011 obs. Do you suggest to choose only one of the above 5 models - appropriately fitted to my equation - and work with that ? In my case model 2 is the most appropriate.

Comment: Yes, then I would go with that. There was a paper about inconsistencies between testing for unit roots and cointegration analysis, but I can’t remember the title. It’s not uncommon.

Comment: also, Engle-Granger 2 step aproach suggests cointegration. I will proceed with only one model then. Since i have two variables, what if I stick only with Engle-Granger? Would that be enough ? Thaks